# Find all classes in Realm DB? (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, realm

Is there a way to find all the classes that exist in the Realm DB?

Example, say you had a Realm database that existed of Dogs, Cats, and Birds. They all have a name property.

You want to search for any object that has a name of "Joe".

Obv you can say

```
realm.Where(Dog.class).Contains()
```

But can you do this dynamically?

something like:

```
realm = Realm.getInstance();
List<?> realmObjects = realm.GetAllClassesThatExtendRealmObject();
for(Object obj : realmObjects)
{
    //search or what not here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is unfortunately not possible with Realm as all query results has to be of the same type. Your best bet is making keeping a list of RealmTypes and let them all implement a interface like so

```
public interface Named {
  public String getName();
  public void setName(String name);
}

public class Foo extends RealmObject implements Named {
  private String name;
  ...
}

public class Bar extends RealmObject implements Named {

}

List<Class<? extends RealmObject?>> types = Arrays.asList(Foo.class, Bar.class);
List<Named> namedResults = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class type : types) {
  List<Named> results = (List<Named>) realm.where(type).equalTo("name", "Joe");
  namedResults.addAll(results);
}
```

However doing that means you loose one of the main benefits of Realm, namely that RealmResults are lazy loaded.